# What Angular Providers do and how to use it?

Tags: html, typescript, dependency-injection, angular-providers

I'm new with Angular. I follow a tutorial from this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wQ5z9SFBlek), and i tried to do/add something that doesn't part of that tutorial. I added a `providers :[EmployeeService]` line to `employee-list.component.ts` and `empployee.component.ts` inside `@component`, and it returns error that said `TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined`. So realize that adding `providers :[EmployeeService]` to some components are unnecessary. I read about Dependency Injection from this [link](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection) but i do not really get what i wanted to know. So can anyone give me a simple explanation how/when/where to use/put providers and how that error happens?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: The angular.io page you linked to explains that in details. Re-read it. https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection#when-to-use-ngmodule-versus-an-application-component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`providers` array tells Angular what services it should instantiate. You can define it on two places:

1. component
2. module

When you use providers in component the service will be available to that and all it's children.

When you use it in module the service will be available for all pipes, directives, components and services in given module.

But you can define it in both if you want - in that case Angular will create two instances of the same service.

For beginning provide your services on the module level.